# Python Script to search for a file

Tags: python, search, file, permissions

i was going through one of the python scripts that Searches for Files and lists their permissions. Im still a learner in python, and while studying this code, i encountered the following questions:

In the lines below, what is the implication of the line **"mode=stat.SIMODE(os.lstat(file)[stat.ST_MODE])" ?**
what is the value returned to **"mode"** ? and how does it function in providing information of the permissions? Would be grateful if someone could explain this.

Also, I need to understand **how the nested for loops within this segment work with respect to getting the desired output of diplaying the filenames and associated permissions ?**

And what is the significance of "level" here ?

Would be very grateful, if anyone could answer the above questions and give any relevant guidance. Thanks in advance.

The entire code is :

```
import stat, sys, os, string, commands

try:
    #run a 'find' command and assign results to a variable
    pattern = raw_input("Enter the file pattern to search for:\n")
    commandString = "find " + pattern
    commandOutput = commands.getoutput(commandString)
    findResults = string.split(commandOutput, "\n")

    #output find results, along with permissions
    print "Files:"
    print commandOutput
    print "================================"
    for file in findResults:
        mode=stat.S_IMODE(os.lstat(file)[stat.ST_MODE])
        print "\nPermissions for file ", file, ":"
        for level in "USR", "GRP", "OTH":
            for perm in "R", "W", "X":
                if mode & getattr(stat,"S_I"+perm+level):
                    print level, " has ", perm, " permission"
                else:
                    print level, " does NOT have ", perm, " permission"
except:
    print "There was a problem - check the message above"
```

Comment: @ Ignacio Hi,basically, i'm looking for answers pertaining to the lines that i've highlighted in bold. I looked into the python documentation for stat.S_IMODE, but needed more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive Python interpreter shell is a good place to play around with snippets of Python code in order to understand them. For instance, to get the mode thing in your script:

```
>>> import os, stat
>>> os.lstat("path/to/some/file")
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=834121L, st_dev=2049L, ...
>>> stat.ST_MODE
0
>>> os.lstat("path/to/some/file")[0]
33188
>>> stat.S_IMODE(33188)
420
```

Now you know the values, check the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) to get their meaning.

In a similar way you could try to answer the other questions yourself.

**UPDATE:**
The value of `mode` is a bitwise *OR* combination of different [mode flags](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chmod). The nested loop "manually" builds the names of these flags, uses `getattr` to get their values and then checks if `mode` includes these values.